# Arithmetic operation on time variable in c-shell

Tags: shell, csh

I need help using time in the c-shell
I want to know how much time it took to execute a script,so i want to do in the following way

> 1.set start_time=time
>   2  script part
>   3.set end_time=time
>   4. set diff=end_time-start_time
>   5.echo "It took $diff seconds"

but i couldn't get the time value using any command.
could any one suggest a command to read the time value in c-shell

Comment: Why don't you just use `time ./script.sh` ?

Comment: script is not shell script. it is c-shell and i want to do it in the makefiles. i cant run bash commends in c-shell once i do csh commnad

Comment: Well but in general, you can use `time` in front of any command to see how long does it take to complete.

Comment: No.. Actually what happens is.. i don't require the whole time taken by a script but i need b/w few commands which takes much time

Comment: By the way time command is giving real,usr,sys like that ..is there a way to format it to get seconds or hours in normal time

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the "date" command, with the format to give you raw seconds:

```
@ start_time = `date +%s`
script part
@ end_time = `date +%s`
@ diff = $end_time - $start_time
echo "It took $diff seconds"
```